# Stuck C++ program (NOT an infinite while loop)

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am writing code to solve a USACO problem (link if you are curious: http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=1013) and I tried running it but my program gets stuck in the while loop. I suspected an infinite while loop so tried cout << "stuck" at every while loop but surprisingly, the console only printed it once and runs forever. Please tell me why.

What I am trying to do in the program:
I am simulating the 2 step process (read the question link I provided) until

1. I perform the process k number of times.
2. I found a cycle.

"arr" is a 2D vector meant to store all the orderings so I can detect a cycle by comparing the 0-th index element and arr.size()-1 -th index element and check for a cycle during every loop.

After we exit, we can use the the mod operator and the array as the answer.

Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector <vector <long long>> arr;

bool found_cycle(){
    if (arr.size() > 1 && arr[0]==arr[arr.size()-1]){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


int main(){
    cin.sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    //freopen("factory.in", "r", stdin);
    //freopen("factory.out", "w", stdout);

    long long n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    
    vector <long long> curr;
    for (long long i=1;i<=n;i++){
        curr.push_back(i);
    }

    long long a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2;
    cin >> a_1 >> a_2 >> b_1 >> b_2;

    long long count = 0;
    while (count < k && (!found_cycle())){
        auto next = curr;
        for (long long i=0;i<=a_2-a_1;i++){
            next[a_2-i] = curr[a_1+i];
        }

        for (long long i=0;i<=b_2-b_1;i++){
            next[b_2-i] = curr[b_1+i];
        }

        arr.push_back(curr);
        curr = next;
        count++;
        //cout << "stuck" << endl;
    }
    if (count!=k){
        arr.pop_back();
        curr = arr[arr.size() % k];
    }

    for (auto e:curr){
        cout << e << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated - but please never ever use ``#include <bits/stdc++.h>`` - you are opening yourself for a lot of pain.

Comment: What are the inputs? Or better, unless the problem is in input handling, remove the input code and hardcode some values that demonstrate your problem.

Comment: You are using user input as indices into vectors, without checking if they are valid.  Undefined Behavior is easy to produce with this code, depending on what your user input is.

Comment: Do you know what `cin.sync_with_stdio(0);` and `cin.tie(0);` actually do? Or have you just blindly copied them from somebody else's code. There aren't many places where those two lines do anything useful.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, step by step, one line at a time, what did you see?

Comment: `if (arr.size() > 1 && arr[0]==arr[arr.size()-1])` --> The following looks a lot cleaner: `return (arr.size() > 1 && arr.front() == arr.back());`